# MySQL tables changed myisam to innodb, mysqldump very slow

Tags: mysql

I had a terrible database server crash. I had about 400 databases. Each db contains about 60 - 70 MyISAM tables. A lot of them crashed because the linux machine retarted for some reason.

I repaired these tables and my provider told me that mysql restores innodb automaticly when it crashed and I had to convert the MyISAM tables to InnoDB.

At first the mysqldump took about 1 hour with MyISAM tables.
Now with INNODB, mysqldump takes about 2 - 3 hours!

How the hell is that possible?
Please help.

here is my mysqldump command

```
$MYSQLDUMP --u=$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD --single-transaction --quick --default-character-set=utf8 --routines --extended-insert --databases $db | gzip > "$BACKUP_DIR/$db.sql.gz" 2> "$BACKUP_DIR/$db.sql.log"
```

Comment: I also tried --disable-keys without any results

Comment: `--disable-keys` would not do anything to changr backup performance, it only changes restore performance, if you restore the file later, and only MyISAM anyway.  What value does `SELECT @@INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE;` return?

Comment: the innodb_buffer_pool_size is 524288000